# Problems requiring environment variables in ubuntu environment

Tags: ubuntu, dotenv

I am developing nodejs in ubuntu. In the development environment, environment variables are read well from the `.env` file. In ubuntu production, only undefined is shown.

When I required the library, I wrote [dotenv npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) usage as shown below:

`require ('dotenv'). config ()`

Please let me know if you have any options that I do not know when requesting a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When copying and pasting locally from the instance to the Ubuntu environment, make sure that the string is truncated.

The first three characters are probably truncated.